# When clicking on an Iframe, no onBlur event is triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, onblur

I am fixing a problem I have with an angular app, which has a propperties panel and an editing `iframe`. To save properties in the panel, I use an `ng-blur` event to save the data.

The problem is, that when I edit data in the properties panel and then go to the `iframe`, no `onBlur` event is triggered. How do I make this happen?

This is an example of a field in the properties panel

```
<textarea class="input-text"
      msd-elastic
      ng-model="asset.title"
      placeholder="click to write title"
      ng-blur="updateProperties()"></textarea>
```

Comment: Add your current code please - preferably as a Codepen / Plunker / jsfiddle :)